# периодическая ошибка ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR на сайте в разных браузерах

Tags: wordpress, nginx, backend

На созданном мною Wordpress сайте для портфолио появляется периодическая ошибка, которая периодически очень серьезно блокирует отображение контента. Я много читал уже на эту тему и писал в техподдержку своего хостинга (smartape). в техподдержке мне сказали, что проблема не на их стороне и мне нужно разобраться с настройками сайта.
Может блокироваться от фотографий и видео, до загрузки шрифтов и даже файлов скриптов.
Ошибка существует не только в Chrome, но как минимум еще и в Mozilla. Ошибка периодическая и случается раз в несколько дней. Большую часть времени все работает как нужно.

На сайте также установлен W3 Total Cache со стандартными настройками + включал кеширование. Делал переход на HTTPS (полностью по гайду от хостинга)

Есть логи с хостинга и они показывают две повторяющиеся ошибки в всегда разных местах.

Tue Feb 05 09:32:25.311335 2019] [lsapi:notice] [pid 32210] [client 217.12.203.5:56378] [host pasekadesign.ru] Backend log: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/user69498/data/www/pasekadesign.ru/wp-content/themes/pasekadesignAjax/reviews-list-content.php on line 26\n, referer: https://pasekadesign.ru/otzyvy/

2019/02/05 09:35:30 [warn] 5617#5617: *66046960 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/8/04/0000395048 while reading upstream, client: 213.87.135.92, server: pasekadesign.ru, request: "GET /wp-content/themes/pasekadesignAjax/video/paseka-team-thick-bw.mp4 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/wp-content/themes/pasekadesignAjax/video/paseka-team-thick-bw.mp4", host: "pasekadesign.ru", referrer: "https://pasekadesign.ru/"

При этом, сначала техподдержка сказала что у меня ошибка в PHP функции - неправильный аргумент для функции `foreach()`, но там стоит стандартный цикл WordPress и он написан правильно. В качестве аргумента приходит массив и функция работает как нужно, цикл выводится. Я проверял строки, на которые ругаются логи.

Полный файл логов в облаке - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1niC3NFdLPiXveDeJgbOV25uPvgRgkh62/view?usp=sharing
Скриншоты ошибок в облаке - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1adf--EfM9eARTCnD3e3ueYEl9bAZEjhm/view?usp=sharing

Не понимаю причины этой ошибки и прошу помощи. Если нужно погружаться в это для помощи, то могу заплатить за работу. Также, более подробную информацию могу предоставить по запросу.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, по какой-то причине, логи неполные. По моему опыту такая ошибка бывает:

- Когда nginx возвращает статус 444 (в конфигурации часто используется как защита от ботов) то есть пустой ответ сервера
- Фатальная ошибка PHP - их у вас нет.
- Проблема с сертификатом

Так или иначе эта ошибка чаще возникает когда сервер возвращает "пустой" ответ, как бы прерывая TLS соединение. Советую настроить максимально логирование и задействовать аггрегатор логов например Papertrail чтобы иметь полную картину что происходит конкретно в момент этих ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А если будет по запросу картинки пустой ответ - ведь можно будет посмотреть в статусе каким кодом завершилось обращение к серверу? Если проблема с сертификатом - то хостинг обратил бы внимание на это? Сейчас попробую установить Papertrail, спасибо за идею.

Comment: В случае с `ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` соединение гибнет на более низком уровне, поэтому статуса ошибки HTTP (200, 500 и тд) видно не будет.

Comment: Сегодня 
снова поймал ошибки - а такая версия логов достаточна? на хостинге это все, что пришло за сегодняшний день по ошибкам - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YOoZpRFHgkq_qoZFKNCrxZoK8cHtMurq/view?usp=sharing А скорее всего, это ошибка на стороне клиента или хостинга?

Comment: Скорее на сервере. Может где то есть `error_reporting(0)`?

Comment: а где проверить/включить эту настройку? error_reporting(0)?

Comment: Это код, который часто присутствует в файлах недобросовестных плагино-кодеров (а ещё чаще в молварях), искать его в файлах `grep -R --include=*.php "error_reporting(0)" ` также может быть и настройка, проверяется `php -i | grep error_reporting`